# No Result getting displayed (I'm guessing I messed up the return statements)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, return

I'm new to python and coding. I'm having trouble figuring out what I did wrong. The question is a time conversion from AM/PM format to 24-hour time format.

```
def timeConversion(s):   
    
    if (s[8:] == "AM"):
            a = int(s[:2])
            c = "0" + str(a) + s[2:8]
            
            if (a == 12) :
                c = "00" + c[2:8]
                  
    else:        
        if (s[8:] == "PM"):
            a = int(s[:2])
            b = 12 + a
            c = str(b) + s[2:8]
            
            if (a == 12):
                c = "12" + c[2:8]             
                  
    return (c)
```

The code is working fine if I input any time in PM but displays nothing in the console if I input AM. Can anyone please help me with this?..Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `s` that you're passing to `timeConversion`?

Comment: I tested your code and found nothing wrong, you need to show the input you used.

Comment: @Abhinav Mathur The type of input that gets passed is in the form of a string, for eg: "12:05:45AM"